# Change image inside link with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have image inside link and i want to change it. When link text is more the image should be arrow down and when link text is less arrow up.

```
<a class="morelink"><img src="Slicice/close.png">Pročitaj više</a>
```

i tried this but it wont work:

```
 $('a').click(function(){
    $('a img').attr('src', 'Slicice/open.png');
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 $(function(){
     $('a').click(function(e){
        $('img', this).attr("src",'Slicice/open.png');
        e.preventDefault();
     });
 });
```

Comment: Please provide more details..so is this anchor tag created dynamically?

Comment: You should provide more details of your issue, edit your question to add more details. is your page reloading while you click the link?

Comment: i just need to toggle 2 images when i click on same link. But for some reason i cant make it work

Comment: yeah please check if this event is triggering, try putting an alert inside function.

Comment: Is your page reloading after click event, did you e,preventDefault(), also check new image source using developer tools after clicking..

Comment: no it is not reloading,tried that. on load i have image,but when i click on link text changes and image disappears. Is it possible it does this because of text change?

Comment: how text is changing..so you have additional code? update your question with details or create a fiddle, we can try to help you then.

Comment: Thanks for your help. i found the answer. i needed to use prepend.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('a.morelink').click(function(){
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'Slicice/close.png');
 });
```

Comment: this should work,but for me it does not. could it be that because i change text of link dinamically it wont change image?

Comment: can you show me the code how are you changing the text?

Comment: i found answer that works. but i have another question... How can i select div ids? i have div-1,div-2,div-3... can i select them at once? i dont want to write script for every div.

Comment: you can select all of them using jquery's start with selector which will select all div's having id start with `div-`, use this code `$('div[id^="div-"]')`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
 $(document).on('click', '.morelink', function(){
    $(this).find('img').attr("src",'Slicice/open.png');
 });
```

The problem with the code you wrote wasa that you are selecting every image inside links and changing them, not just the link you clicked.

So here we use `$(document).on` to make sure the event is fired in any dynamically added element, `$(this)` inside the function refers to the link you clicked. The rest is obvious.